# Get Coupon code on cart page and checkout page?

Tags: magento1.9.0.1

I have only one coupon code, I want to display this coupon code on the cart page and the checkout page.

Comment: Hi Vinod@ you can use the below code which will be useful. thanks

Comment: it is not working

Comment: let me know exact error you are getting? first of all whether your coupon code applying properly..?

Comment: it is neither display any error nor any result.

Comment: could you share the screenshot please

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have got it using this code .
Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to Get Coupon code on cart page and checkout page

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment on the last answer's solution.

My webshop is using Magento 1.9.3.2.

I the answer's solution at the bottom of the file:

magento/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml

This is the code to add to local.xml:

```
<block type="core/template" name="getcoupon" output="toHtml" template="custom/info.phtml">    

    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>    

</block>
```

See screenshot of the added code in my local.xml:

https://snag.gy/F1ACQs.jpg

But this not result in showing the coupon code on the checkout page.

To make it work right do I also have to add this same code to the file:

app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/custom/info.phtml ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get the Coupon code on the cart page and checkout page:

```
magento/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml

<block type="core/template" name="getcoupon" output="toHtml" template="custom/info.phtml">    
...    
    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>    
...    
</block> 

app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/custom/info.phtml
```