# How to display Coupon code on cart page and checkout page?

Tags: coupon-codes, onestepcheckout, magento-1.9.3.2

My webshop is using Magento 1.9.3.2 using default OnePageCheckout.

See screenshot:

https://snag.gy/OinRzW.jpg

I found this article answere solution for my question:

[Get Coupon code on cart page and checkout page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160409/get-coupon-code-on-cart-page-and-checkout-page/264474#264474)

I add below answere solution code from the question article at the bottom in file:

magento/app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/local.xml

```
<block type="core/template" name="getcoupon" output="toHtml" template="custom/info.phtml">    

    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>    

</block>
```

See screenshot of the added code in my local.xml:

https://snag.gy/F1ACQs.jpg

But this not result in showing the coupon code on checkout page.

To make it work right do I also have to add this same code to the file:

app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/custom/info.phtml ?

Comment: please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256303/how-to-show-promo-code-or-coupon-code-on-checkout-page-in-magento-1-9 it may help you